# Redundant Character scape PEP8 Coding Style in Python

Tags: python, pep8

The following function is working fine, but I am struggling to learn and solve some PEP8 coding rules and write it properly:

```
import re

stringtext= " I don't care the following expression 10/10, so lets work with this text." 

def del_page_num(text):
    import re
    r = re.compile(r'[0-9][0-9]\/[0-9][0-9]', flags=re.I | re.X)
    aux = r.findall(text)
    for item in aux:
        text = text.replace(item, "")
    return text

# output:
    del_format(stringtext)
    " I don't care the following expression, so lets work with this text."
```

Given a text this function delete the expression like: "00/00" but the expression `\/` is redundant in terms of pep8 coding style.

How it could be edited to get a correct expression?

## Solution

Pycharm is teaching some good practices of coding (pep-8 style), another whay to define de function without any pycharm "correction advice" would be the next one:

```
def del_page_num(text):
    import re
    aux = re.findall(r'\b(\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})\b', texto)
    pattern = re.compile(r"\b(" + "|".join(aux) + ")\\W", re.I)
    return pattern.sub("", text)
```

Comment: PEP8 says *nothing* about escapes. Yes, you can just drop the backslash, it is **not needed** but this is not a style violation.

Comment: Pycharm is underlining **\/** in yellow as redundant expression, so I understood it was in a wrong way. Once I delete the backslash is working properly at first sight. thanks anyway @MartijnPieters

Comment: PyCharm is just trying to teach you about redundant backslashes. That has nothing to do with PEP8 however. *Some* of the PyCharm warnings and suggestions may be based on PEP8 but don't equate the two.